# SSRS - Conditionally select elements from XML data source

Tags: sql, xml, reporting-services

I have a simple XML tree:

```
<manufacturer = 'Audi'>
  <make = 'A4'>
    <color>Black</color>
    <build_date>11th May 2014</build_date>
  </make>
</manufacturer>
```

I know I can query data using:

```
<Query>
  <ElementPath>
    manufacturer{}/make{color, build_date}
  </ElementPath>
</Query>
```

What I'd like to do is filter the results using the date attribute.  Like a SQL WHERE clause.  So in this example it's cars that are built after a specified date.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need set a filter on the data set in SSRS on the Build_date Field:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255287.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can filter the result from an xml. An example to your query is as below

```
SELECT 
[xmlField].value('(/person//firstName/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as FirstName,
[xmlField].value('(/person//lastName/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as LastName
FROM [myTable]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If it's XML, how would I find the table name?

Comment: Then you have to write nested queries for this

Comment: the above answer is assuming the xml is coming from the DB. based on the syntax in the question. I think an xml data source is being used and hence the above xpath will not work